# create a new array of objects and merge the objects with same value

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Im trying to build a new array of objects based on `specs` array of objects.
There are some similar question already but didn't help me.

```js
const specs = 
[ 
  { label: 'Brand', value: 'Nike' },
  { label: 'Age range', value: '8 to 13' },
  { label: 'Age range', value: '14+' }
 ]
```

I want to skip the "Brand", which works with my code, and I want that if there are multiple objects with the same `label`, they need
to be merged in a unique object which contains that label and `ALL` of the values together, so the output will have brand removed and the other values merged:

```json
[
  { label: 'Age range', value: '8 to 13 - 14+' }
 ]
```

Here's my code:

```js
 var newSpecs = []

    for (let x = 0; x < specs.length; x++) {
      if (specs[x].label === 'Brand') continue

      for (let j = x + 1; j < specs.length; j++) {
        if (specs[x].label === specs[j].label) {
          specs[x].value += ' - ' + specs[j].value
        }
      }
      newSpecs.push({ label: specs[x].label, value: specs[x].value })
    }
    return newSpecs
```

But this simply does not work, it created multiple merged age range.
I tried another time by using `delete` and other things but got me "cannot read label of undefine", so I'll keep this way,
but I cannot figure out how to do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i return two objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438423/how-can-i-return-two-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Your code seems correct. Could you show the value that newSpecs returns?

Comment: ```[
    { label: 'Age range', value: '8 to 13 - 14+' },
    { label: 'Age range', value: '14+' }
  ]``` @MRMarkII

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://repl.it/@SilvanoHirtie1/test#index.js)

Comment: Oh, right. You need to create a string, and concat all the values in it. So when you finish the for, you can choose any label (index 1 for example, because if you choose 0 is brand) and put the string that you created in the for in the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive multiple "Age range" because you have nested loops. Try this approach using `.reduce()` for grouping:

```js
const specs = [ 
  { label: 'Brand', value: 'Nike' },
  { label: 'Age range', value: '8 to 13' },
  { label: 'Age range', value: '14+' }
];

var newSpecs = specs.reduce((res, curr) => {
  if (curr.label === 'Brand') return res;
  
  var group = res.find((el) => el.label === curr.label);
  if (group) {
    group.value += ' - ' + curr.value;
  } else {
    res.push(curr);
  }

  return res;
}, []);

console.log(newSpecs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to separate out labels

```js
const specs = [
  { label: "Brand", value: "Nike" },
  { label: "Age range", value: "8 to 13" },
  { label: "Age range", value: "14+" },
];
const labelMap = {};
specs.forEach((sp) => {
  if (sp.label !== "Brand") {
    labelMap[sp.label] = labelMap[sp.label] || { label: sp.label, value: [] };
    labelMap[sp.label].value.push(sp.value);
  }
});
const op = Object.values(labelMap).map((el) => ({
  ...el,
  value: el.value.join(" - "),
}));
console.log(op);
```